# How to read request parameter values Using HandlerInterceptor in spring?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm using HandlerInterceptor to trigger all the events/actions happens in my applications and save it to audit table. In table I'm saving the information like servername, session, parameters etc..

So using HandlerInterceptor how can I read all those parameters values and the pathvariable values what I'm passing in my controller.

Here is my code :

```
    public class AuditInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
            LOG.debug("URL path"+request.getRequestURI());
                return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        LOG.debug("URL PATH :"+request.getRequestURI());

    } 

}
```

My controller class enter code here::

```
public class ABCDController {
@RequestMapping(value="categories",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Category> getCategoryList(@RequestParam String divisions){
        return service.getCategoryList(divisions);
    }
}
```

So how can I read the parameter name and values using HandlerInterceptor's HttpServletRequest request object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Servlet API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html) provides a way to read the Request Parameters. For example,

[`ServletRequest.getParameterMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29) returns a map of key-values of the request parameters.

However, for Path variables and values, I don't know if Spring MVC offers a simplified way of doing it, but using Servlet API again, you can read the URI using [`HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29). You'll have to have your own logic to split it up into appropriate Path parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get the variables and its values as a map using the following,

```
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        final Map<String, String> variableValueMap = (Map<String, String>) request
                .getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);

        variableValueMap.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println("Key:"+k+"->"+"Value : "+v));

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What about the method parameter arguments?